# Invalid name for Parameter for FullSeriesCollection

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I've been using curves names that have a "Δ" as the first character [CharW(916)] in the name, this has not caused any problem until recently. The code snippet below worked fine in the past, but for the "last few months" -- can't be more definite -- this has caused Excel to crash inelegantly without error/warning. Currently running Microsoft 365 Version 2205 (Build 15225.20204 Click to Run)

```
vw = ChrW(916) & "Cases." & vc(1, i) ' e.g., The curve name (vw) is "ΔCases.W10" 
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(vw).IsFiltered = True ' Excel now barfs on this line...
```

I'be changed the "Δ" character to "d" as an obvious work-around, but that's not really the point... Any observations?